# Why doesn't `conda env export` list all pip packages?

Tags: python, pip, conda

To list all of the packages in my active environment in a format that resembles `pip freeze`:

```
conda env export > myoldenv.yml
```

My `myoldenv.yml` after running `(pytorchd) root@trainman-k8s-job-6efe31ad-6a62-4852-aa1c-85e172854578-9wzjt:/home/code-base/VQVAE_Summarization-main/src# conda env export`:

```
name: pytorchdchannels:
  - anaconda
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=conda_forge
  - _openmp_mutex=4.5=1_llvm
  - absl-py=0.11.0=py38h578d9bd_0
  - aiohttp=3.7.3=py38h25fe258_0
  - async-timeout=3.0.1=py_1000
  - attrs=20.3.0=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - blinker=1.4=py_1
  - brotlipy=0.7.0=py38h8df0ef7_1001
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h7f98852_4
  - c-ares=1.17.1=h36c2ea0_0
  - ca-certificates=2021.1.19=h06a4308_1
  - cachetools=4.1.1=py_0
  - certifi=2020.12.5=py38h06a4308_0
  - cffi=1.14.4=py38h261ae71_0
  - chardet=3.0.4=py38_1003
  - click=7.1.2=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - cryptography=3.3.1=py38h3c74f83_0
  - cudatoolkit=11.0.221=h6bb024c_0
  - dataclasses=0.7=py38_0
  - ffmpeg=4.3.1=h3215721_1
  - filelock=3.0.12=py_0
  - freetype=2.10.4=h5ab3b9f_0
  - fsspec=0.8.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - future=0.18.2=py38h578d9bd_3
  - gmp=6.2.1=h58526e2_0
  - gnutls=3.6.13=h85f3911_1
  - google-auth=1.24.0=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - google-auth-oauthlib=0.4.1=py_2
  - grpcio=1.33.2=py38heead2fc_2
  - idna=2.10=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - importlib-metadata=3.4.0=py38h578d9bd_0
  - intel-openmp=2020.2=254
  - jpeg=9b=h024ee3a_2
  - kiwisolver=1.3.1=py38h2531618_0
  - lame=3.100=h7f98852_1001
  - lcms2=2.11=h396b838_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.33.1=h53a641e_7
  - libblas=3.9.0=7_mkl
  - libedit=3.1.20191231=h14c3975_1
  - libffi=3.3=he6710b0_2
  - libgcc-ng=9.3.0=h5dbcf3e_17
  - libgfortran-ng=7.3.0=hdf63c60_0
  - libiconv=1.16=h516909a_0
  - libpng=1.6.37=hbc83047_0
  - libprotobuf=3.13.0.1=h8b12597_0
  - libstdcxx-ng=9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
  - libtiff=4.1.0=h2733197_1
  - libuv=1.40.0=h7b6447c_0
  - llvm-openmp=11.0.0=hfc4b9b4_1
  - lz4-c=1.9.2=heb0550a_3
  - markdown=3.3.3=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - mkl=2020.4=h726a3e6_304
  - mkl-service=2.3.0=py38he904b0f_0
  - multidict=5.1.0=py38h27cfd23_2
  - ncurses=6.2=he6710b0_1
  - nettle=3.6=he412f7d_0
  - ninja=1.10.2=py38hff7bd54_0
  - nltk=3.5=py_0
  - numpy-base=1.19.2=py38hfa32c7d_0
  - oauthlib=3.0.1=py_0
  - olefile=0.46=py_0
  - openh264=2.1.1=h8b12597_0
  - openssl=1.1.1k=h27cfd23_0
  - packaging=20.8=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - pillow=8.1.0=py38he98fc37_0
  - pip=20.3.3=py38h06a4308_0
  - protobuf=3.13.0.1=py38he6710b0_1
  - pyasn1=0.4.8=py_0
  - pyasn1-modules=0.2.7=py_0
  - pycparser=2.20=pyh9f0ad1d_2
  - pyjwt=2.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyopenssl=20.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyparsing=2.4.7=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - pysocks=1.7.1=py38h578d9bd_3
  - python=3.8.5=h7579374_1
  - python_abi=3.8=1_cp38
  - pyyaml=5.3.1=py38h497a2fe_2
  - readline=8.0=h7b6447c_0
  - requests=2.25.1=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - requests-oauthlib=1.3.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - rsa=4.7=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - setuptools=51.1.2=py38h06a4308_4
  - six=1.15.0=py_0
  - sqlite=3.33.0=h62c20be_0
  - tensorboard-plugin-wit=1.7.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - threadpoolctl=2.1.0=pyh5ca1d4c_0
  - tk=8.6.10=hbc83047_0
  - tqdm=4.56.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - typing-extensions=3.7.4.3=0
  - typing_extensions=3.7.4.3=py_0
  - urllib3=1.26.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - werkzeug=1.0.1=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - wheel=0.36.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - x264=1!152.20180806=h14c3975_0
  - xz=5.2.5=h7b6447c_0
  - yaml=0.2.5=h516909a_0
  - yarl=1.6.3=py38h25fe258_0
  - youtube-dl=2021.2.10=py38h578d9bd_0
  - zipp=3.4.0=py_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
  - zstd=1.4.5=h9ceee32_0
  - pip:
    - alembic==1.4.3
    - banal==1.0.1
    - bert-score==0.3.7
    - breadability==0.1.20
    - dataset==1.4.3
    - docopt==0.6.2
    - joblib==1.0.0
    - lxml==4.6.2
    - mako==1.1.4
    - matplotlib==3.3.3
    - pandas==1.2.0
    - pycountry==20.7.3
    - pyrouge==0.1.3
    - python-editor==1.0.4
    - pytz==2020.5
    - regex==2020.11.13
    - sacremoses==0.0.43
    - sqlalchemy==1.3.22
    - sumy==0.8.1
    - tokenizers==0.9.4
    - transformers==4.2.1
prefix: /opt/conda/envs/pytorchd
```

However, when I run `pip freeze` in the same conda environment, I see many more python packages:

```
(pytorchd) root@trainman-k8s-job-6efe31ad-6a62-4852-aa1c-85e172854578-9wzjt:/home/code-base/VQVAE_Summarization-main/src# pip freeze
absl-py @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/absl-py_1606235506191/work
aiohttp @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/aiohttp_1605734406386/work
alembic==1.4.3
APScheduler==3.5.3
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/attrs_1605083924122/work
backcall==0.2.0
banal==1.0.1
bert-score==0.3.7
blinker==1.4
boto3==1.9.79
botocore==1.12.253
breadability==0.1.20
brotlipy==0.7.0
cachetools @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/cachetools_1596822027882/work
certifi==2020.12.5
cffi==1.14.5
chardet==4.0.0
click==7.1.2
clipboard==0.0.4
cryptography==3.4.6
cycler==0.10.0
dataset==1.4.3
decorator==4.4.2
docopt==0.6.2
docutils==0.15.2
filelock==3.0.12
Flask==1.1.2
fsspec @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/fsspec_1608050797851/work
future @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/future_1610147327521/work
gevent==21.1.2
google-auth @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/google-auth_1608136875028/work
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
greenlet==1.0.0
grpcio @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/grpcio_1604365522020/work
idna==2.10
importlib-metadata @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/importlib-metadata_1610355167281/work
ipython==7.16.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jedi==0.18.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
jmespath==0.10.0
joblib==1.0.0
jupyterlab-zip==1.0.3
kiwisolver==1.3.1
lxml==4.6.2
Mako==1.1.4
Markdown @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/markdown_1603668500820/work
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.3.3
mkl-service==2.3.0
multidict @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/multidict_1607367757617/work
newrelic==4.18.0.118
nltk @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/nltk_1592496090529/work
numpy==1.19.5
oauthlib==3.0.1
olefile==0.46
packaging @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/packaging_1607785313469/work
pandas==1.2.0
parso==0.8.1
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pillow_1609786786540/work
prompt-toolkit==3.0.17
protobuf==3.6.0
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.7
pycountry==20.7.3
pycparser==2.20
Pygments==2.8.1
PyJWT @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/pyjwt_1609976754451/work
pyOpenSSL==20.0.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
pyperclip==1.8.2
pyrouge==0.1.3
PySocks @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/pysocks_1610291447907/work
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-editor==1.0.4
pytz==2020.5
PyYAML==5.4.1
regex==2020.11.13
requests==2.25.1
requests-oauthlib @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/requests-oauthlib_1595492159598/work
requests-toolbelt==0.9.1
rsa @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/rsa_1610280765105/work
s3transfer==0.1.13
sacremoses==0.0.43
sensei-sdk==3.0.2
sensei-toolkit==1.0.3b0
senseinbs==2.15
six==1.15.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.22
sumy==0.8.1
supervisor==4.2.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/tensorboard-plugin-wit_1603349307347/work/tensorboard_plugin_wit-1.7.0-py3-none-any.whl
threadpoolctl @ file:///tmp/tmp9twdgx9k/threadpoolctl-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
tokenizers==0.9.4
tqdm==4.59.0
traitlets==4.3.3
transformers==4.2.1
typing-extensions @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/typing_extensions_1598376058250/work
tzlocal==2.1
urllib3==1.26.3
wcwidth==0.2.5
Werkzeug==1.0.1
yarl @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/yarl_1605429457708/work
youtube-dl @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/youtube-dl_1612980304778/work
zipp @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/zipp_1603668650351/work
zope.event==4.5.0
zope.interface==5.2.0
```

E.g. `numpy==1.19.5` is in `pip freeze` but not in `conda env export`.

Why?

I use:

```
> pip -V
pip 19.0.3 from /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
> conda -V
conda 4.6.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `conda` only keeps track of the packages it installed
- `pip freeze` will give you the packages that were either installed using pip package manager or they used setuptools in their setup.py so `conda` build generated the egg information.

[conda vs pip](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2016/08/25/conda-myths-and-misconceptions/)

Downgrading the pip may fix this issue, you can check this out:
[conda issues](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7581)

Comment: "*conda only keeps track of packages it installed*" - just isn't true.  Both the `list` and `env export` commands detect pip-installed packages.